# How can I make Intel Core i7 Mac perform at i3 or i5 level?

Tags: performance

I need to do some performance testing, and I need the MacBook to behave at i3 or i5 speeds. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I have the MacBook Pro Retina / macOS Sierra 10.12.6 / 2.2GHz Intel Core i7.

Comment: What sort of task is being measured? If it’s CPU bound, you might have a simple formula. If not, there might be no measurable difference.

Comment: @bmike It's a SAP Hybris (eCommerce platform) task. What I want the application to do is to copy/duplicate X number of records (in a database). There's also some business logic involved. I'd like to see how long this takes on i3/i5 level, versus i7 level. I realize the SSD might still not give me the difference/delay I need to see. Or, is there some other way / possibility?

Comment: It is impossible to accurately model i3/i5 speeds on an i7. The number of small differences are two great, and no known, publically available cycle-correct emulator for the i3/i5 exists. If you do not need to know exact numbers, you can use cpubenchmark.net to get benchmark numbers for each CPU and just apply that factor to your own time measurements. It will only be vaguely accurate, and only when the task you're measuring is solely CPU-bound.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% what you're looking for (in that the controls are not fine grained enough to say "make my i7 4770HQ perform like an i3 4150"), but something that will tweak your CPU's TurboBoost settings can help.

One application that can do so is [Turbo Boost Switcher](https://www.rugarciap.com/turbo-boost-switcher-for-os-x/) - it may be worth giving it a try. Another way is to disable CPU cores using [Instruments.app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html) (part of XCode). You could try a combination of the two to slow down your machine, perhaps benchmarking as you go (eg, using [Geekbench](https://www.geekbench.com/) or similar) until you reach the desired level of performance.